# Div next to two vertical aligned divs

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I know that this question has already been asked several times but none of them seem to work for me or they're "too complicated" for my example.

I have three divs. Two of them are aligned vertically. The other one should be next to them and should have the same hight as the other two together.

**It should look like this:**

[image: div next to two vertical aligned divs]

**This is what I have so far:**

```css
.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #fffdea;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon{
  border: 1px solid lightgreen;
  width: 130px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.info{
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="icon">
    <p>Icon</p>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Number</p>
  </div>
    <div class="info">
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Number</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Have a look at my [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mc0rnq87/41/)

Comment: Here is working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1uhts6Lt/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="icon">
    <p>Icon</p>
  </div>
  <div class="info-set">
  <div class="info">
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Number</p>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Number</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: #fffdea;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.icon {
    border: 1px solid lightgreen;
    width: 130px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.info-set {
    width: 100%;
}
.info {
    border: 1px solid aqua;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's better to wrap your right side div(.info) with a parent div.

**Try this one , it could help**

```css
.wrapper{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #fffdea;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.icon {
  border: 1px solid lightgreen;
  width: 30%;
}

.right-set {
  width: 75%;
}

.info {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="icon">
     <p>Icon</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-set">
        <div class="info">
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Number</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Number</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something needs to have a height set, either the wrapper or the icon. I also set height 50% of the info divs and changed box-sizing to border box for the contained elements.

```css
.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #fffdea;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 130px;
}

.icon{
  border: 1px solid lightgreen;
  width: 130px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.info{
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="icon">
    <p>Icon</p>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Number</p>
  </div>
    <div class="info">
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Number</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved using Flexbox and wrapping the **info** divs in a container.

```
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="icon">
    <p>Icon</p>
  </div>
  <div class="info-container">
    <div class="info">
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Number</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Number</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #fffdea;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.icon{
  border: 1px solid lightgreen;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.info-container{
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.info{
  border: 1px solid aqua;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also attempt to use css Grid.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  /*1fr unit is one fraction of the remaining space available. So I have divided the space into two tracks. One longer than the other*/
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
}

.icon {
  background: #a03;
  /*Run the icon div in two rows height but take one track width as the rest*/
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.info {
  background: #bccd03;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="icon">
    <p>Icon</p>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Number</p>
  </div>
    <div class="info">
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Number</p>
    </div>
</div>
```